# aligning the image on the right side of text box

Tags: html, css, styles

I have the below form,

[image]

I want the green image on the right side of text box instead of getting below the text box.

The image is visible if the field is validated.

My css

```
<style type="text/css"> 
        .formcontainer{
            border-radius: 10px;  
            -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
            box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc; 
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc; 
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;  
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            padding:15px;
            width: 300px; 
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        form {
            margin:0 auto; 
            text-align:left;
            width:100%;
            background:#fff;    
            behavior: url(./border-radius.htc);
            font-family:Calibri;
            height: auto;
        }
        fieldset.border{
            overflow:hidden;
            border:1;
            -moz-border-radius:5px;  
            border-radius: 5px;  
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            margin:3px 0;
            padding:10px;
            border:solid 1px #C0C0C0;
        }
        fieldset.no_border{
            overflow:hidden; 
            border:0; 
            padding:0 0 10px 0; 
            margin:0;
        }
        fieldset.no_border_submit{
            overflow:hidden;
            border:0;
            text-align:center;
            margin:3px 0;
        }
        input.effect {

            border:1px solid #ccc;  
            height: 20px;
            padding:3px;
            width:70%;
            font-size:14px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;

        }


        .cssSubmitButton {          
            font-size: 12px;
            background: #fff no-repeat 4px 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 20px 6px;
            color: #333;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.9em;
            border-radius: 15px;
            -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #999;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #999;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline:none;
        }

        .cssSubmitButton:visited {}

        .cssSubmitButton:hover {
            border:1px solid #333;
        }

        #subscribeForm span{
            margin-left: 0px;
            color: #b1b1b1;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-style: italic;
            display:none;
        } 
        fieldset.border{
            overflow:hidden;
            border:1;
            -moz-border-radius:5px;  
            border-radius: 5px;  
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            margin:3px 0;
            padding:10px;
            border:solid 1px #C0C0C0;
        }
        fieldset.no_border{
            overflow:hidden; 
            border:0; 
            padding:0 0 10px 0; 
            margin:0;
        }
        fieldset.no_border_submit{
            overflow:hidden;
            border:0;
            text-align:center;
            margin:3px 0;
        }
        #subscribeForm input.error{
            background: #f8dbdb;
            border-color: #e77776;
        }

        #subscribeForm span.error{
            color: #e46c6e;
            display:block;
        }
        #success{
            display:none;
        }
        #button{
            text-align:center;
        }

    </style>
```

my html

```
<div class="formcontainer">
<form method="post" action="" id="subscribeForm" name="subscribeForm">
    <fieldset class="no_border">
        <label>Login ID: </label><br /><input type="text" class="effect" name="login_id" id="login_id"  autocomplete="off" ><img id="login_id_correct" style="display:none" src="./images/tick.png" />
        <span id="login_idInfo">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="no_border">
        <label>Name: </label><br /><input type="text" class="effect" name="name" id="name"  autocomplete="off" >
        <span id="nameInfo">What's your name?</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="no_border">
        <label>Contact No: </label><br /><input type="text" class="effect" name="contact_no" id="contact_no"  autocomplete="off" >
        <span id="contact_noInfo">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="no_border">
        <label>Email: </label><br /><input type="text" class="effect" name="email" id="email"  autocomplete="off" >
        <span id="emailInfo">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="no_border">
        <label>Password: </label><br /><input type="password" class="effect" name="password1" id="password1"  autocomplete="off" >
        <span id="password1Info">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!</span>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="no_border">
        <label>Retype: </label><br /><input type="password" class="effect" name="password2" id="password2"  autocomplete="off" >
        <span id="password2Info">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!</span>
    </fieldset>

    <div id="button">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribeForm"/>
    </div>
    <div id="success">
        <strong>Data Saved Successfully.</strong>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Also is there any way i an create a css class for it so that the image is added to the right side of text box once each text box is validated.

Comment: What's the HTML look like?

Comment: @TimWasson sorry updated the question

Comment: You must be using jQuery/JavaScript to show the icon when the form is validated...

Comment: Is there any css on the img or input that isn't included above? Like the input or image being treated as a block element? It should work as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cardeo/8mA7u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
fieldset input {
  float:left;
}
```

maybe you also need to set the input to inline or inline block if you have set it to block previously.

http://jsbin.com/akiviw/1/edit

or change js

```
$('#login_id_correct').css('display','block')
```

to

```
$('#login_id_correct').css('display','inline-block')
```

Comment: i overlooked part of your question. I am sure the problem occurs because of javascript. With js you make toggle the image display:none and display:block. Can you post the js?

Comment: either change that to "inline-block" or see my updated answer

Comment: I hope your solution is cross browser compatible

Comment: I agree with this answer, make the image display inline-block. Make sure the parent `<fieldset>` element has enough width to accommodate for both `<input>` and the `<image>` elements to line up next to each other.

Comment: inline block is pretty cross browser. unless you want ie6 support then maybe go with inline instead.

Comment: @user1721135 yes its working now. Is there any way I can create a common class that when applied will display the image in front of the respective text box. instead of adding image to all text boxes. I mean if I can apply image class using js

Comment: you could use absolute position for this i guess.

Comment: sorry i did not understand that

Comment: if you want to display the image in front of the input, you can use absolute position for that. or change the inputs and images place in html

Comment: Setting CSS float:left on the image will bring it to the front of the text box, but it will shift the text box right and it may look ugly. `$('#login_id_correct').css('float','left')`

Comment: any one with an idea to make a common class displaying image when i add the class via js. If its at all possible...

Comment: .class {display:inline-block;} then js .toggleClass("class");

Comment: @user1721135 no you did not get my question what i want is the image to be declared in a css class and then i can apply that class via js to which ever text box are validated instead of hard coding image code after every text box

Comment: you could use a background image for this obviously